# I have single-element arrays. How do I change them into the elements themselves?

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas

Importing a JSON document into a pandas dataframe using `records = pandas.read_json(path)`, where path was a pre-defined path to the JSON document, I discovered that the content of certain columns of the resulting dataframe "records" are not simply strings as expected. Instead, each "cell" in such a column is an array, containing one single element -- the string of interest. This makes selecting columns using boolean indexing difficult. For example, `records[records['category']=='Python Books']` in Ipython outputs an empty dataframe; had the "cells" contained strings instead of arrays of strings, the output would have been nonempty, containing rows that correspond to python books.

I could modify the JSON document, so that "records" reads the strings in properly. But is there a way to modify "records" directly, to somehow strip the single-element arrays into the elements themselves?

Comment: Sounds like you're doing normalization? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#normalization (Would help to give an actual example!) :)

Comment: Thanks Andy. I didn't try normalization on the json itself, but looks like I could do that to solve the problem. I will try that for my next json output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** After clarification, I believe this might accomplish what you want while limiting it to a single iteration over the data:

```
nested_column_1 = records["column_name_1"]
nested_column_2 = records["column_name_2"]

clean_column_1 = []
clean_column_2 = []

for i in range(0, len(records.index):
    clean_column_1.append(nested_column_1[i][0])
    clean_column_2.append(nested_column_2[i][0])
```

Then you convert the clean_column lists to Series like you mentioned in your comment. Obviously, you make as many nested_column and clean_column lists as you need, and update them all in the loop.

You could generalize this pretty easily by keeping a record of "problem" columns and using that to create a data structure to manage the nested/clean lists, rather than declaring them explicitly as I did in my example. But I thought this might illustrate the approach more clearly.

Obviously, this assumes that all columns have the same number of elements, which maybe isn't a a valid assertion in your case.

**Original Answer:**

Sorry if I'm oversimplifying or misunderstanding the problem, but could you just do something like this?

```
simplified_list = [element[0] for element in my_array_of_arrays]
```

Or if you don't need the whole thing at once, just a generator instead:

```
simplifying_generator = (element[0] for element in my_array_of_arrays)
```

Comment: OK thanks. I was able to do 

    `cat2 = [element[0] for element in records['cat']]`
    `records['cat2'] = Series(cat2, index=records.index)`

I can then delete the original "cat" column, rename cat2 to cat, and would be good to go. 
However, I continue to wonder if there is a faster way to do this, if I have multiple columns with this kind of problem and I don't wish to iterate over all these columns.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. You could do a single iteration by slicing out all of the columns that have the nested arrays, then only iterating once, updating all of the columns in each loop. I'll put an example of what I'm suggesting in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help Nacho.